# Google Analytics tracking code "Not Installed" even it is

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have tried to install google analytics on site http://vykup-bronzu.sk.

Problem is that, it still shows "Not installed" status for tracking code.

I have figure out some google searching and using GA debuger, but still no idea where the problem is :(

Tracking code is in head tag.

Debuger result:

```
    _gaq.push processing "_setAccount" for args: "[UA-34054138-1]":  ga_debug.js:18
    _gaq.push processing "_trackPageview" for args: "[]":  ga_debug.js:18
    Track Pageview ga_debug.js:18
    Tracking beacon sent!
    utmwv=5.3.4d&utms=7&utmn=197771223&utmhn=vykup-bronzu.sk&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1440x900&utmvp=1423x355&utmsc=32-bit&utmul=sk&utmje=1&utmfl=11.3%20r31&utmdt=V%C3%BDkup%20bronzu%20%7C%20Lutoby%20s.r.o.&utmhid=264692647&utmr=-&utmp=%2F&utmac=UA-34054138-1&utmcc=__utma%3D251021313.380013673.1344828700.1344828700.1344828700.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D251021313.1344828700.1.1.utmcsr%3D(direct)%7Cutmccn%3D(direct)%7Cutmcmd%3D(none)%3B&utmu=q~ ga_debug.js:18
    Account ID               : UA-34054138-1
    Page Title               : Výkup bronzu | Lutoby s.r.o.
    Host Name                : vykup-bronzu.sk
    Page                     : /
    Referring URL            : -
    Hit ID                   : 264692647
    Visitor ID               : 380013673
    Session Count            : 1
    Session Time - First     : Mon Aug 13 2012 05:31:40 GMT 0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
    Session Time - Last      : Mon Aug 13 2012 05:31:40 GMT 0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
    Session Time - Current   : Mon Aug 13 2012 05:31:40 GMT 0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
    Campaign Time            : Mon Aug 13 2012 05:31:40 GMT 0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
    Campaign Session         : 1
    Campaign Count           : 1
    Campaign Source          : (direct)
    Campaign Medium          : (none);
    Campaign Name            : (direct)
    Language                 : sk
    Encoding                 : UTF-8
    Flash Version            : 11.3 r31
    Java Enabled             : true
    Screen Resolution        : 1440x900
    Browser Size             : 1423x355
    Color Depth              : 32-bit
    Ga.js Version            : 5.3.4d
    Cachebuster              : 197771223 ga_debug.js:18
```

Comment: did you just add that code? I think it takes some time before it changes the status

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. I deployed the analytic code as instructed but I was seeing the status as "tracking code not installed".
So I left it as it is for a day and checked the status next day. Next day also, it was showing same status but it was also showing the visitor's data. 
So I guess it takes a while to update the status as in my case it is still showing "not intalled" status. 
BTW I have installed analytic yesterday only :-)

On second day status was also updated to "receiving data". So I think it takes a day to update that flag status.

Answer (score 0):

"Once you find the code snippet, copy and paste it into the bottom of your content, **immediately before the </body>** tag of each page you are planning to track."

http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/topic.py?topic=19783

You've installed it within the <head>

Comment: Google actually contradicts itself. Here it says to put the code just before the closing </head> tag:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en&utm_id=ad

Comment: I'd ignore that and put it before the </body> tag - that way the browser can render the page before submitting the analytics data, otherwise the users will have to wait

Comment: The JS that google provides for analytics is running asynchronously now, so it doesn't block rendering when in <head>.

Comment: "Paste your snippet (unaltered, in it’s entirety) into every web page you want to track. Paste it immediately before the closing </head> tag." [set up](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?rd=1)

Answer (score 0):

Once you find the code snippet, copy and paste it into your web page, just before the closing  tag*. If your website uses templates to generate pages, enter it just before the closing  tag in the file that contains the  section. (Most websites re-use one file for common content, so it's likely that you won't have to place the code snippet on every single page of your website.)

From your link.  Clearly, you're supposed to install it WITHIN the head section.

Answer (score 0):

**Same problem, some fixes:**

1) It might show not installed, and still be installed and providing information. It's a b**ch.

2) Another JS script might be failing before the execution of the GA script, which makes the GA script show these kind of errors. To check that, you can use firebug console.

3) It's clear to me that not only analytics, but other google technologies and software are being modified and extended. Ex: Angular.Js During the last year I found and reported a few many problems. I wouldn't trust too much on GA results either.

3) Personal advice: Download an alternative like Piwik.